# Unable to pass list and dictionary in function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is the requirement :
We have a nested object, we would like a function that you pass in the object and a key and get back the value.

```
object = {“a”:{“b”:{“c”:”d”}}}
key = a/b/c
value = d
```

Code :

```
from functools import reduce
def deep_get(dictionary,keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda z, key: z.get(key, default) if isinstance(z, dict) else default, keys.split("/"), dictionary)

object = {'a':{'b':{'c':'d'}}}

key = "a/b/c"
print (deep_get(object, key))
```

Issue : If I am passing "a" or "a/b" in key I am getting output, but expected output should be None. So can you help me here or is there any better way to do it, I am open to all

Thank you

Comment: You can check for every key if the value is of type dict, then return None

Comment: Can you help me a bit, i didn't got you, it will be really helpful :)

Comment: Why do you expect the output for ``"a"`` and ``"a/b"`` to be ``None``? Their value clearly is the respective nested ``dict``. Do you want to disallow returning ``dict``s entirely?

Comment: yes i want none for a and a/b

Answer (score 2):

Just check the type of the returned value from the `reduce` function, and return only if is `str`, as like here:

```
from functools import reduce
def deep_get(dictionary,keys, default=None):
    a = reduce(lambda z, key: z.get(key, default) if isinstance(z, dict) else default, keys.split("/"), dictionary)
    if isinstance(a, str):
        return a
    else:
        return None
        

object = {'a':{'b':{'c':'d'}}}

key = "a/b/c"
print (deep_get(object, key))
```

input: `"a/b/c"`
output: `d`

input: `"a/b"`
output: `None`